# Break and restart Linux command when specific text appears

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, logging

To simplify the situation as much as possible, let's say I'm tailing a log file that gets rotated out when an application shutdown occurs. Since the file changes, the tail stops. In order to continue the tail a keyboard interrupt is required and then the command is run again. Here's an example:

```
$ tail -f some-log-file.log
log line
log line
...etc...
log line
log line
Some app restarting...
^C
$ tail -f some-log-file.log
log line
log line
...etc...
```

So what I'd like to find is some simple way to restart the tail when the text "Some app restarting..." is encountered. I've thought of programs I could write to monitor processes or similar, but I feel like this should be possible as a one-liner or short bash script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while true; do
  sed '/Some app restarting/q' <(exec tail -f some-log-file.log)
  kill -9 $!
done
```

Here's a breakdown of what that does:

- `while true; do`: start an infinite loop
- `sed '/Some app restarting/q'`: send its input to its output, and terminate when it gets "Some app restarting"
- `<(command)`: run *command* in a subshell in the background and give its output to the previous command
- `exec`: replace the (sub)shell with the following command, instead of forking to run it
- `kill -9 $!`: kill the most recent background process started, which is the tail -f (without this, it will seem to work but a tail process will be permanently left over every time the app restarts)
- `done`: end the infinite loop

Comment: Lots of useful tricks here, from sed's `/q` to `<(exec ...)`. I have this running and will accept your answer tomorrow once I verify it works as intended.

Comment: I made some small adjustments for my situation but this concept worked great, thank you!